# Is it possible to make web app proactive rather than reactive?

Tags: java, web-applications

Web applications traditionally follow the request/response cycle, where a request is made by a user or another web app. However, I'm curious if it is possible to make a web app automatically initiate certain tasks upon it's deployment to a app server. For example, let's say we have a web app that retrieves and processes data. Is it possible to configure this app to automatically retrieve and process data when certain criteria are met, rather than needing a request from a user/another web app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is using task schedulers like cron for example. Although one might argue, that such tasks no longer are a web application, but local applications unning on the server instead.

Comment: I'd also go with cron here. It could be just an addition to the existing webapp. Like doing something to the webapps database every now and then.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Java servlet containers, it might be possible they have some builtin in scheduling features.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If the data in your example are in files, then you can use a **FileWatcher** to monitor the folder and initiate some action when a new file lands there.

Here is one [example](http://www.koders.com/java/fid20485F149D64E2E122B3A1CA42159D83B3117110.aspx?s=cdef%3Astring) of a very simple one, just to give you an idea of how it works:

```
package pilrcedit;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileWatcher implements ChangeListener
{
  private static final int FILE_MODIFIED=MODIFIED;

  Hashtable files=new Hashtable();
  ChangeListeners listeners=new ChangeListeners();

  public FileWatcher()
  {
    Preferences.addChangeListener(this);
  }

  public void objectChanged(Object source,int id,Object data)
  {
    checkFiles();
  }

  private void checkFiles()
  {
    for(Enumeration e=files.keys();e.hasMoreElements();)
    {
      File f=(File)e.nextElement();
      if (f.lastModified()!=((Long)files.get(f)).longValue())
      {
        files.put(f,new Long(f.lastModified()));
        notifyListeners(f);
      }
    }
  }

  public void addFile(File f,ChangeListener listener)
  {
    files.put(f,new Long(f.lastModified()));
    listeners.add(f,listener);
  }

  public void removeFile(File f,ChangeListener listener)
  {
    listeners.remove(f,listener);
  }

  public void notifyListeners(File f)
  {
    listeners.fireObjectChanged(f,this,FILE_MODIFIED,f);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include that in the deploy process itself. Or include that initial request to the webpage in the deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you want to do certain things during the deployment I think you can use spring here to perform certain tasks or load something in memory (cache) during deployment. For example in the application context xml you can have this:-

```
<bean id="someCache" class="com.my.company.MyCache"
          init-method="load">
  <!-- <property> as needed -->     
</bean>
```

MyCache class could be something like below:-

```
class MyCache{
        public void load() {
             //do your deployment work
    }
}
```